# Using Drush permissions issue

Tags: ubuntu, drupal

Using my own non-root account I installed Drush on my Ubuntu 14.04 server using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install drush
```

My problem is whether I use sudo or not with the same user account, I get **Could not download project status information from http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x** as the following shows:

```
axel@ITS-DEV-SVR:/var/www$ drush dl drupal-7.34
Could not download project status information from                   [error]
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x
axel@ITS-DEV-SVR:/var/www$ sudo drush dl drupal-7.34
Could not download project status information from                   [error]
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x
axel@ITS-DEV-SVR:/var/www$
```

Are there settings, permissions
Can anyone please offer some insight into how to resolve this?

**UPDATE**:

The server is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Below is the output of executing a drush download in verbose mode.

```
drush -v dl drupal-7.34
Loading version_control engine.                                         [notice]
Loading package_handler engine.                                         [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading release_info engine.                                            [notice]
Downloading release history from                                        [notice]
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x
Executing: wget --version
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_filectSEpS http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x
Undefined variable: xml updatexml.inc:404                               [notice]
Could not download project status information from                   [error]
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x
Command dispatch complete                                               [notice]
```

**UPDATE#2**

It's worth adding that the website is configured as a multisite even though it's running a single website

Comment: Can you try the verbose version of drush `drush -v dl drupal-7.34` and paste the output. It has worked for me.

Comment: @Ketan: I added feedback to my question

Comment: It looks like a php version issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1402120

Comment: @sisko : what's the current status of this question? Do you ever find out what the problem/solution was?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Its the same. I believe it's due to settings.php not being in the usual place because the site is a multisite configuration

Comment: Aha, "multi-site", that's important info you did not include in your question (consider editing the question to include that info). Also note that I just "answered" your question (99% sure your issue is because of the multi-site setup, so you need to "tell" Drush to which (sub) site you want the Drush cmd(s) to be applied. Sometimes I run into the same (hard to understand) error msg (in a multi site), which is why I'm pretty sure ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a multi-site installation, then Drush needs to know to which "site" (one of the multi-sites supported by the Drupal instance) the Drush command is to be applied.

Therefor make sure to FIRST navigate to the subfolder "sites". Try to run the same Drush command(s). I believe it will then assume you want the sites/all subfolder to be updated. If you still have the same issue, then try to navigate to the sites subfolder "default" (or any other subfolder corresponding to any of the other sites related to this multi-sites setup, and try again.